# Is it possible to change a delete to an update using triggers?

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

Is there any way in Firebird to execute an UPDATE instead a DELETE through a trigger?

This is possible in Microsoft SQL Server by declaring the triggers as "INSTEAD".

The problem is that we have an application that uses a Firebird database and we want to prevent the deletes of records and mark then as "deleted" (a new field), but without showing any error to the user, and "cheating" the app.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with tables (but I'll need to check), but it is possible with views.

Comment: can this be made on VIEW instead of TABLE ?

Comment: option: in AFTER DELETE trigger do INSERT and re-add the row back into the table, with altered flag and what not. It would change row's RDB$DB_KEY though, if any library could had used it. // it would still be `"cheating" the app` as the app does not know about the "deleted" flag and would still see those rows as if they were not deleted. A VIEW could be hiding such rows making the compatibility layer for the app.

Comment: @Arioch'The That might work, though it could break applications querying using RDB$DB_KEY with a dbkey_scope set to session (on the other hand, that is probably quite esoteric to do anyway).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but VIEW route, while much more proper, would require maybe long copying of the table. AFAIR Firebird does not provide for renaming an already existing relation. // I was more concerned not with "querying" but with a briefcase-like libraries. That create a virtual table inside the client app, let the app do ISAM-like edit/delete/append operations on rows, and then try to flush it back into the server using some kind of "ApplyCachedUpdates" mega-call. The logic of such libraries might be quite convoluted.

Comment: @Arioch'The ... Is a good option... But it fails if the table is referenced by foreign keys...

Comment: Arioch 'The. YES! It can be made on VIEWs. That's the way I solved it. 

If a View has a trigger, then the trigger is the responsible of making the real update or delete on the underlying table.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with tables, but you can do it with views. Views can have triggers on insert, update and delete that modify the underlying table(s). See also [Updatable Views](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-view-create-updatable) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference.

In short, create a table for the data, add a view, add triggers that insert/update/delete through the view to the underlying table. Users can then use the view as if it is a table.

### An example

I'm using Firebird 3, but this will work with minor modifications in Firebird 2.5 and earlier.

A table `example_base`:

```sql
create table example_base (
  id bigint generated by default as identity constraint pk_example_base primary key,
  value1 varchar(100),
  deleted boolean not null default false
)
```

A view `example`:

```sql
create view example (id, value1) 
  as 
  select id, value1 
  from example_base 
  where not deleted;
```

Do not create the view with `with check option`, as this will disallow inserts as the absence of the `deleted` column in the view will prevent Firebird from checking the invariant.

Then add an insert trigger:

```sql
create trigger tr_example_insert before insert on example
as
begin
  if (new.id is not null) then
    -- Don't use identity
    insert into example_base(id, value1) values (new.id, new.value1);
  else
    -- Use identity
    -- mapping generated id to new context 
    -- this way it is available for clients using insert .. returning
    insert into example_base(value1) values (new.value1) 
      returning id into :new.id;
end
```

The above trigger ensures the 'by default as identity' primary key of the underlying table is preserved, and allows `insert into example .. returning` to report on the generated id.

An update trigger

```sql
create trigger tr_example_update before update on example
as
begin
  -- Consider ignoring modification of the id (or raise an exception)
  update example_base 
    set id = new.id, value1 = new.value1 
    where id = old.id;
end
```

The above trigger allows modification of the primary key; you may want to consider just ignoring such a modification or even raising an exception.

And finally a delete trigger:

```sql
create trigger tr_example_delete before delete on example
as
begin
  update example_base 
    set deleted = true
    where id = old.id;
end
```

This trigger will mark the record in the base table as deleted.

To use this, just grant your users select, insert and update privileges to the view (and not the table).

The only caveat I'm aware of is that defining foreign keys will need to point to `example_base`, not to `example`, and the behavior of foreign keys will be slightly off. The record in the base table will continue to exist, so the foreign key will not block deletion. If that is something that is necessary, you will need to emulate constraint behavior (which could be tricky).

Comment: shouldn't the update trigger also check for null auto-gen new-ID ? From here, may insert and update triggers be merged and use update-or-insert statement, just to make one "if" less in the DB ?

Comment: "to emulate constraint behavior (which could be tricky)" guess all the trick would be to make a secondary triggers-maintained table with all the columns used in all the FK's and do FK against that table. De-facto creating ad hoc "materialized view". Granted, just as with M.V. it might  be seen as a waste of disk space

Comment: @Arioch'The If you really want to be able to regenerate ids through updates, then yes, but that is hardly a normal case, and here I only forward the update. Merging the update and insert triggers to a single triggers is IMHO a bad idea especially by using `update or insert`; this intentionally distinguishes inserts from updates to avoid incorrect updates from accidentally generating records as that could potentially be exploited by someone with update but not insert privileges.

Answer (score 0):

YES! It can be made on VIEWs. 
That's the way I solved it. 
If a View has a trigger, then the trigger is the responsible of making the real update or delete on the underlying table.... So... a DELETE trigger that makes an UPDATE to the table solved my problem.